# Evento de click não obtém dado

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Galera, sou iniciante nesse mundo todo, e estou querendo implementar uma função em um aplicativo meu. Achei um projeto disponível para download e mudei todo o código para o meu favor, mas no final de deparei com algo, que parece simples, mas me imbolou D+. Após cortar a imagem, é gerado um 'link' em data-result. Eu preciso pegar esse resultado e enviar para meu aplicativo através do SetWebString, mas não funcionou então criei algo básico para me ser mostrado um evento com esse resultado, mas não consigo de maneira nenhuma. Passei a noite toda buscando na net e não achei nada. dito que todas as informações necessárias estão no final do código. Eu não me lembro ao certo de onde consegui esse código, por isso não colocarei crédito ao autor aqui, mas quem quiser pode copiar e modificar a seu bel prazer. Esse código tinha muito mas funções, mas eu removi para me atender somente ao que eu quero. Para utilizar no App Inventor, eu preferi colocar 90% do código em um único arquivo. TML, JavaScript e CSS e o Stack disse que o código é grande para pôr aqui, então vou colocar o link dele do Dropbox. Obrigado desde já.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/syxlg3cb4rb1630/index.html?dl=0

Comment: David, o ficheiro do dropbox tem 1528 linhas! Não podes esperar que alguém tenha tempo para ajudar. Por favor coloca o código aqui, e somente a parte relevante para a pergunta. Aí vamos poder ajudar melhor.

Comment: Sim, eu disse no texto que a parte que preciso ser analisada é no final do código. Existem apenas dois botões no final, e ao clicar em Cortar quero que eel gere um evento para mim, um evento que está bem acima desse botão, de Result-data. O restante do código acima não é para ser analisada, somente o final.

Comment: Ok, então podes clicar em [edit] e juntar o código aqui na pergunta. Nós ajudamos a formatar o código se for preciso.

Comment: Eu fui colocar, mas o site disse que o limite de linha tinha sido atingido e o código ia só a metade. Por isso eu disponibilizei no Dropbox. Eu imagino que seja algo bem 'bobo' de fazer, mas não consegui de maneira nenhuma.